# C# repeating Enum elements

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, enums, artificial-intelligence

thanks in advance. I'm a Unity developer.
So I have my AI states in enum converted to a list.

```
public enum IdleState
{
BasicIdle,
PlayingWithKids,
Playfull,
Curious,
Bored,
MoveToCamera,
Waiting,
PlantMode,
Shy,
Crying
}

public List<IdleState> availableIdleStates = new List<IdleState>()
{
IdleState.BasicIdle,
IdleState.PlayingWithKids,
IdleState.Playfull,
IdleState.Curious,
IdleState.Bored,
IdleState.Waiting,
IdleState.PlantMode,
IdleState.Shy,
IdleState.Crying
};
```

I'm controlling the order of execution through my public list in my inspector witch works fine, however I would like to have basic idle (enum int = 0) execute multiple times in my inspector order of execution. Although when the list gets to my second basic idle it restarts and gets stuck between the two basic idles I assume its because its value in enum is 0, but i really don't know whats causing this, any help would be a blessing. thanks guys!

```
 private void FixedUpdate()
{
   
    if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > prevIdleStateChangeTime + currentStateDuration)
    {
        int i = availableIdleStates.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(currentIdleState))+1;
       
        if (i >= availableIdleStates.Count)
        {
            i = 0;
            
        }
        changeState(availableIdleStates[i]);
    }
    switch (currentIdleState)
    {
        case IdleState.BasicIdle:
            if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > subStateChangeTime + subStateDuration)
            {
               
                subStateChangeTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
                switch (randInt)
                {
                  //something
                }
            }
            break;

        case IdleState.PlayingWithKids:
         
            if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > subStateChangeTime + subStateDuration)
            {
                
                int randInt = Random.Range(0, 3);
                subStateChangeTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
                switch (randInt)
                {
                  //something
                }
            }
            break;
```

etc..

every state change this method is being called:

```
  private void changeState(IdleState NewState)
{
    currentIdleState = NewState;
    prevIdleStateChangeTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
    mover.resetParameters();
    subStateChangeTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
    subStateDuration = -1;
 }
```

Comment: You're looping over that list, right? Could you provide the code related to the loop and make it clear where exactly it gets stuck?

Comment: @MostafaF.Rad just edited my post

Comment: The list and looping works fine until I try to add to it the same state a second time through my inspector.

Comment: So every state holds movement and behavior parameters and every available state has its own definition. So for example having basic idle to execute more than once in my list.

What I want is to do is to be able to have the exact same idle state run multiple times in different indexes in my public inspector list and actually go to the rest of the elements without being stuck in an infinite loop.

the changing of states is time based and works fine by the index order in my inspector. the problem is when I try to add the same idle state multiple times in my inspector list

Answer (score 0):

```
availableIdleStates.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(currentIdleState))
```

Here. If first and second object is the same this will always find first occurence of your duplicated state (id = 0), your script changes it to id = 1 but in next update again first element is found and your id is back to 0. You should have field for that int value instead of finding index on list if you want to have duplicate elements.

Comment: Please my dear can you show me how?

Comment: your "currentIdleState" should be of type int and to convert it to actual IdleState use availableIdleStates[currentIdleState]